# How to check that type is inherited from some interface c#

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance, interface

I have following:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType());

foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
{
    MyAttribute attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(MyAttribute))    as MyAttribute;
     if(attr != null && [type is inherited from Iinterface])
     {
        ...
     }

}
```

How can i check that type is inherited from MyInterface? Does is keywork will work in this way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No, `is` only works for checking the type of an *object*, not for a given `Type`. You want [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
if (attr != null && typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
```

Note the order here. I find that I almost *always* use `typeof(...)` as the *target* of the call. Basically for it to return true, the target has to be the "parent" type and the argument has to be the "child" type.

Answer (score 7):

Check out IsAssignableFrom
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Hi
You can use `type.GetInterfaces() or type.GetInterface()` to get the interfaces which the type implements.

Answer (score 0):

Given worst case scenario;

if you are using reflection over all properties in a class...

```
public List<PropertyInfo> FindProperties(Type TargetType) {

     MemberInfo[] _FoundProperties = TargetType.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Property,        
     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, new
     MemberFilter(MemberFilterReturnTrue), TargetType);

     List<PropertyInfo> _MatchingProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

     foreach (MemberInfo _FoundMember in _FoundProperties)  {
     _MatchingProperties.Add((PropertyInfo)_FoundMember); }

     return _MatchingProperties;

}
```

IInterface is some generic interface

> ```
>    public void doSomthingToAllPropertiesInDerivedClassThatImplementIInterface() {
>
>         IList<PropertyInfo> _Properties = FindProperties(this.GetType());
>         foreach (PropertyInfo _Property in _Properties)
>         {
>
>             if (_Property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IInterface)))
>             {
>                 if ((IInterface)_Property.GetValue(this, null) != null)
>                 {
>                       ((IInterface)_Property.GetValue(this, null)).SomeIInterfaceMethod();  
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Realise this is very late, but leaving it here for reference:
I found the is operator does the job - from MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.71).aspx

Using resharper on Jon Skeets answer, gave me "is" as a suggestion as well.